# Hidden Values in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode6, uipickerview

As beginner in iOS Developing I struggle with specific implementation of`UIPickerView`.
I already know how to create`UIPickerView` with specific data.

My goal is a bit complicated though - I would like this PickerView to print me selected value. For example - like in simple currency calculator - I pick EUR currency and I have value "4.30" printed out.

FYI -  I need to pass this value to another ViewController just to be multiplied.
Any help will be appreciated!

Here's sample code - for now I am still trying to understand what should I do here

```
@interface SecondViewController ()

{
    NSArray *currency;
}
@property NSArray *currency;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize currencyValue;
@synthesize currency;
- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];

}

- (NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    return [self.currency count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:
            (NSInteger)component {
    return self.currency[row];

     }

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    [currencyValue setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Exchange rate of currency : %@",[currency objectAtIndex:row]]];

}


-(IBAction)currencyValue:(id)sender {



}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.currency = @[@"EUR", @"PLN", @"CFH", @"DKK", @"SEK", @"NOK"];
```

Comment: Feel free to attach a code sample for more detailed answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `UIPickerViewDelegate` you can set the rows' titles with `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` as [described](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPickerViewDelegate/pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:) in the documentation.

The `UIPickerView`'s `selectedRowInComponent:` [will return](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectedRowInComponent:) you the current selected row: use the previous data source with this index to retrieve the current selected title.

Comment: Thank You for explaining me that in simply words.
I am still learning to read with understanding the Code Documentation, and before asking this question I've read it - but so far I couldn't understand it fully. It is never late to learn :)